# Has my Bonsai died?

Tags: plant-health, bonsai

When I first purchased my Bonsai, the tree was so beautifully green. I purchased it about a year ago. It has been this color for about three to four months now. I'm wondering if it has died or just waiting on the season to change to change back to its original color. Has it died on me? I still water it as I usually do.
 [image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

[image: 4]

[image: 5]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine this was once a Juniper bonsai - I'm sorry to confirm its an ex-bonsai, and is dead. Juniper's not an easy bonsai to keep - if you're not sure its dead, cut one of stems and check inside - if its dead, it will be dry and brown inside, if not, it should look moist.

UPDATE: I'd say its dead, even looking at that cut stem. When conifers develop  dead, brown needles, those parts don't regrow - sometimes the tips are still green and they carry on growing, but the dead, brown parts don't ever regenerate. One for the compost heap I'm afraid.

Comment: I've just added a picture of the stem I cut. It's a white-creamish color and looks dry. What are your thoughts?

Comment: It is VERY DEAD. Everything suggests that you've kept it inside. There is nowhere near enough light indoors to keep a juniper alive. It needs to be outside in pretty much full-sun. What happens indoors is much like you were put on a 100 calorie a day diet.

Comment: @LOSTinNEWYORK see updated answer

Comment: Oh boy...guess its a lost. Trash it goes. Atleast I tried. Thanks for all feedback